# Web scraping an HTML table in Cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, web-scraping, cheerio

I have a problem with a web scraping project.  Here is a sample of the page I need to scrape:

```
<table style="position...">
   <thead>..</thead>
     <tbody id="leaderboard_body">
       <tr bgcolor="#155555">..</tr>
       <tr bgcolor="#155555">..</tr>
       <tr bgcolor="#155555">..</tr>
                ...
     </tbody>
</table>
```

for more detail, here is the page: [World Leaderboards](http://www.dota2.com/leaderboards/?l=english#europe)

I want to access the information within the tr tags but I can't achieve it. I can't find the tbody tag with simple code, like this, and I don't know why:

```js
var cheerio = require("cheerio");
var url = "http://www.dota2.com/leaderboards/?l=french#europe";
var http = require("http");

// Utility function that downloads a URL and invokes
// callback with the data.
function download(url, callback) {
  http.get(url, function(res) {
    var data = "";
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
      data += chunk;
    });
    res.on("end", function() {
      callback(data);
    });
  }).on("error", function() {
    callback(null);
  });
}

download(url, function(data) {
  if (data) {

var $ = cheerio.load(data);
var content = $('tbody').text();
console.log(content);
    }
  else
    console.log(err);
  
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the table doesn't exist in the HTML, it's inserted with javascript after the page has loaded, and can't be scraped the traditional way.

Always look at the source, not just the live view in the console.

Doing just a minimum of research shows that the table is built from JSON that is gotten with a request to

http://www.dota2.com/webapi/ILeaderboard/GetDivisionLeaderboard/v0001?division=europe

And there you have all the data you need preformatted and ready, without having to scrape HTML

Comment: i feel dumb now ... at least ty that was easy and i was sure something like that was the cause of my trouble